# Hibernate + Maven + Glassfish

Tags: hibernate, jpa, maven, jpa-2.0, glassfish

Tenho um Projeto Maven, que utiliza Hibernate, e está com todas as dependências ok.

Já criei a `connection pool` no glassfish. O problema é que mesmo a classe mapeada com as anotações do hibernate dica dando erro falando que deve ser mapeada pelo persistente.xml, esse arquivo existe e está configurado corretamente e o projeto foi facetado com JPA, essa é a primeira vez que utilizo o Maven é necessário a utilização de algumas configurações adicionais, alguém tem idéia do que pode estar ocorrendo?

Comment: Qual erro acontece ao subir o servidor? Podes adicionar o erro ao post?

Comment: No momento não posso lhe enviar, não estou com o computador assim que possível lhe envio o erro não é um log do servidor é um erro gerado pelo inspetor do eclipse.

Comment: O problema apontado pelo inspetor do Eclipse é: Class _"com.financeiro.Pessoa" is managed, but is not listed in the persistence.xml file_

Comment: A mensagem de erro é clara: todas as entidades precisam ser listadas no persistence.xml. Neste mesmo arquivo você também pode setar para false o atributo *exclude-unlisted-classes*, de modo a não precisar listar as entidades. Me deixe uma mensagem caso ainda esteja com o problema que eu posso postar uma resposta.